# How to add content to HTTP header?

Tags: php, curl

I'm new to PHP/cURL and I need to add these content elements to the `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER`:

```
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="media[]"; filename="http://www.example.com/pic/test.jpg"
```

PHP:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: ' . $this->get_DST($status)));

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'status='.rawurlencode($status);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
```

Comment: use $post_data = array('data' => '@/tmp/test.png') at CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS; It will automatically set the headers above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$headers = array( 'Authorization: ' . $this->get_DST($status),
                  'Content-Type: application/octet-stream',
                  'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="media[]"; filename="http://www.example.com/pic/test.jpg'
                 );
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$headers = array(
    'Authorization: ' . $this->get_DST($status),
    'Content-Type: application/octet-stream',
    'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="media[]"; filename="http://www.example.com/pic/test.jpg"'
);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php